# Is there a name for font families (such as fangchan-secret) that are used to prevent web scraping?

Tags: html, css

In trying to scrape some data from the website of a housing agency in China (the name of the agency is Anjuke) to gather data for a small personal project I realized that all of the numbers on the website are visually displayed as numbers, but are digitally read as obscure Chinese characters.

Is there a name for this kind of a font or this kind of a technique more specific than "anti-scraping measures"?

**Additional information about this specific case**:To see this in action you can click on any of the listings from  [the Anjuke website](https://bj.zu.anjuke.com/?from=navigation), and then attempt to copy-and-paste the price (or any HTML element that has the "strongbox" class), and you will see that instead of pasting the number is pastes and obscure Chinese character (such as 驋, 齤, 麣, 龤, or 龒).

Looking at the CSS revealed that these numbers have a font of "fangchan-secret", and a bit of quick googling linked to [a blog post in Chinese by zhyuzh3d](https://www.jianshu.com/p/9975de57b0ce). I read some Chinese, although not loads. This blog post appears to be a Chinese explanation of how how fangchan-secret is a method to prevent to prevent webscraping, and also an explanation of how to get around around this preventative measure.

Comment: Also nice for the ones using assistive devices...

Comment: You could sort-of call this an icon font because it maps unicode values that don't make sense otherwise in the given context into visual symbols, here they just happen to be numbers, not icons.